# Tradingview Login with Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, rest, tradingview-api

I try to create a code which can login with rest to trading view. The result should be a session ID as response, but I dont get any usefull response.

My code is this:

```
$loginHeaders = [
                'Origin' => 'https://www.tradingview.com',
                'User-Agent' => $userAgent,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Referer' => 'https://www.tradingview.com'
            ];
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            Log::debug(json_encode($loginHeaders));
            $login = Http::withHeaders($loginHeaders)->post('https://www.tradingview.com/accounts/signin/username=${username}&password=${password}&remember=on');
            Log::debug(json_encode($login));
            $cookies = $login->cookies();
            Log::debug(json_encode($cookies));
            $this->sessionid = $cookies['sessionid'];
```

and my response is this:
{"cookies":{},"transferStats":{}}

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs you are following? Seems you are just doing a GET request to their webpage, not the API. You should do a POST request to the `/authorize` endpoint according to [their REST API specification](https://www.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/#tag/Authorization)